# How to get custom background under jumbotron?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

```css
#particles-js{
  background:rgba(0, 10, 14,.8);
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:55px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  min-height:700px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#jumbotron{
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
  /* position: fixed; */
  /* z-index:-101; */
  /* height: 100vh; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <title>Video</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="particles-js">
 <div class="jumbotron text-center mt-3" id="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Welcome</h1>
  <p class="lead">Jot down ideas for your next YouTube videos</p>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Add Video Idea</a>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function () {
      console.log('particles.json loaded...');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a jumbotron inside a `div`, which has some particle effect.

[image]

As can be seen in the image these particles starts below the jumbotron. How can I have thses below the jumbotron also?

index.html

```html
<div id="particles-js">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center mt-3" id="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">{{title}}</h1>
    <p class="lead">Jot down ideas for your next YouTube videos</p>
    <a href="/ideas/add" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Add Video Idea</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style .css

```css
#particles-js {
  background: rgba(0, 10, 14, .8);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#jumbotron {
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
  /*position: fixed; */
  /* z-index:-101; */
  /* height: 100vh; */
}
```

But if I use the `position:fixed` property of jumbotron, I got the desired effect but jumbotron moved to the extreme left of the page.

[image]

How can I have it like the second picture with jumbotron in the center?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried set #particles-js "top" to 0?

Comment: I tried but it behaved the same way

Comment: What is the odds that you will create a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) snippet for this? It will be much easier for us to debug it and help you.

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: ok, I have added the snippet. But you won't be able to see the particles as it comes from a json file. Was not able to included that in the snippet .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the code generated with particles js. Your #particles-js div with background starts at the top, when you will set top to 0. But the generated code with particles is positioned to bottom. You have to change this in settings or in css.

Comment: I have a navbar at top thats why I have put top:55px so that the div starts just below the navbar

Comment: Anyway you can just keep the fixed position and position your jumbotron to the center. .jumbotron{position: absolute; left: 50%; right: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)}

Comment: I tried by setting top to 0, then this black div covers my navbar.

Comment: You can try with z-indexes than. But try to position jumbotron absolutely as I said before with #particles as fixed.

Comment: I added this part  left: 50%; right: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%). But that pushed the part jumbotron under jumbotron, so welcome was not visible. I used transform: translate(-50%, -0%); its working as expected. Can you please explain why we used transform as left:50 and right:50 should have did the job